# For each - Looping through sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My first post here. I've been learning VBA for a little over a month and so far, I've managed to do what I want by browsing other posts.

My problem is that the code I've written only applies to the first worksheet, but I want it to apply to all the worksheets in the workbook. My code is as follows:

```
Sub invoicepayable()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ActiveSheet.Range("J34").Value > 0 Then

            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\me\Desktop\" _
            & Range("C8").Value & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "MMM - YYYY"), _
            Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

        End If
    Next Ws

End Sub
```

Basically I want this to only export receivable invoices (`J34>0` means they owe us money). However, when I run this macro, it exports the first worksheet in the workbook, but no subsequent workbooks, even if `J34>0` is true in all worksheets. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Withing the loop you're checking `ActiveSheet` - switch that to `Ws`.  Looping though worksheets doesn't automatically activate each sheet (and your code will run more reliably if you don't do that...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the advice of Tim Williams in the comment above and replace ActiveSheet with Ws. I've also replaced `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` - this is a lot cleaner and ensures that your code is being ran against the correct Excel workbook. Check out this new version below, with some error checking;

```
Public Sub invoicepayable()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If (Not IsEmpty(Ws.Range("J34").Value)) And (Not IsError(Ws.Range("J34").Value)) Then
            If (IsNumeric(Ws.Range("J34").Value)) And (Ws.Range("J34").Value > 0) Then

                Ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\me\Desktop\" _
                & Range("C8").Value & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "MMM - YYYY"), _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False

            End If
        End If

    Next Ws

End Sub
```

Comment: It's now giving me Runtime Error 13 - Type mismatch on `If Ws.Range("J34").Value > 0 Then`  I also realized that I do have some #N/A in the referenced cell when we didn't do business with a counterparty that month. Changing that line of code to `If (Not IsError(Ws.Range("J34").Value) And Ws.Range("J34").Value > 0) Then` gives the same error message.

Comment: @iboblaw - I like your thinking. The reason for the error must be that the value in one of the J34 cells in the workbook is of the wrong type. Either it's an error, or maybe it's just in the wrong format, I'm not entirely sure. I've updated my answer with some more error checking, please give it a go and let me know how you get on.

Comment: The line `If (IsNumeric(Ws.Range("J34").Value)) And (CInt(Ws.Range("J34").Value) > 0) Then` Was returning a Error 6 - Overflow. I'm guessing that's because some of the values weren't integers (we want every cent!). I changed that line of code to: `If (IsNumeric(Ws.Range("J34").Value)) And (Ws.Range("J34").Value) > 0 Then` and it's working! Woohoo!

Comment: @iboblaw - Awesome, glad you got it sorted :-)